# Convert several rows to one row with several columns

Tags: sql, pivot, azure-sql-database

I am trying to figure out how I can create a SQL query that can return one aggregated row with several columns based on another table with several rows. To start, I will have a quite large table with millions of rows with order data where I for one item_id could have one row with currency USD and one row with currency EUR. For each rows I will also have additional data, e.g. number_of_items. This table will look something like this:

```
Item_id Currency    Value   Nbr_of_items    Total_nbr_of_items  Item_share 
1   USD 200 100 200 0,50
1   EUR 40  20  200 0,10
1   CNY 35  80  200 0,40
2   HKD 50  60  100 0,60
2   GBP 20  40  100 0,40
3   CNY 14  50  50  1,00
4   USD 10  30  30  1,00
```

My end-goal is to create one table with one row for each item_id, which can hold up to 3 different currencies. The following table is what I would like to create, but not sure how I would do it… Any ideas? Would very much appreciate your help!

EDIT: just updated the table as I would like to have the currencies in the order based on the item_share, so largest item_share should be currency_1, second largest item_share should be currency_2 etc.

```
Item_id Currency_1  Value_1 Nbr_of_items_1  Currency_2  Value_2 Nbr_of_items_2  Currency_3  Value_3 Nbr_of_items_3
1   USD 200 100 CNY 35  80  EUR 40  20
2   HKD 50  60  GBP 20  40  NULL    NULL    NULL
3   CNY 14  50  NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL
4   USD 10  30  NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL
```

Comment: Which DBMS product are you using? "SQL" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product. Please add a [tag](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging) for the database product you are using. [Why should I tag my DBMS](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/)

Comment: You want a "pivot".

Answer (score 0):

You can use `row_number()` and conditional aggregation:

```
select item_id,
       max(case when seqnum = 1 then currency end) as currency_1,
       max(case when seqnum = 1 then value end) as value_1,
       max(case when seqnum = 1 then num_items end) as num_items_1,
       max(case when seqnum = 2 then currency end) as currency_2,
       max(case when seqnum = 2 then value end) as value_2,
       max(case when seqnum = 2 then num_items end) as num_items_2,
       max(case when seqnum = 3 then currency end) as currency_3,
       max(case when seqnum = 3 then value end) as value_3,
       max(case when seqnum = 3 then num_items end) as num_items_3
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by item_id order by num_items desc) as seqnum
      from t
     ) t
group by item_id;
```